# Does the sum of two functions that each go to infinity as $x$ goes to $0$ also go to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be real functions such that $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\infty$$ That is, the two-sided limit of each function as $x$ approaches $0$ is equal to positive infinity. Is it necessarily true that $$\lim_{x\to0}(f+g)(x)=\infty$$ I can't come up with two example functions to reject this proposition, but if somebody can explain to me if/why it is true I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried just using the definition of "going to infinity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true in general indeed by definition

$$\forall M_1 \quad \exists \delta_1 \quad 0<|x|<\delta_1 \quad f(x)>M_1$$

$$\forall M_2 \quad \exists \delta_2 \quad 0<|x|<\delta_2 \quad g(x)>M_2$$

therefore with $\delta_3=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$

$$\forall M_3=M_1+M_2 \quad \exists \delta_3 \quad 0<|x|<\delta_3 \quad f(x)+g(x)>M_3$$